# In Android studio when i click back button it should not allow the user to go to previous activity and it should be in the same activity

Tags: android

I m new to android could someone help me . 
In Android studio when i click back button it should not allow the user to go to previous activity and it should be in the same activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

add this to your activity

Comment: @Guruprasad This will be the answer for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onBackPressed()` method of activity and use it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the `onBackPressed()` method & do nothing over there.
You can leave a message via toast if needed.